# Is it ok to use oracle 11g client with a 10g server?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, odp.net

I am creating a .NET program that uses odp.net, specifically the 11g version. Our oracle server is running 10g. I am too late in the development process to make a change. Am I heading for trouble? Have you had any experience running 11g client against a 10g server?

Comment: Oracle has historically been very good with backwards compatibility.  As the advice below states, check the compatibility matrix and you should be OK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use odp.net 11 with Oracle server 9, 10 and 11. And yes I have tried all those combinations.

You can use for example odp.net 11 for retrieving geographical information (datatype=mdsys.sdo_geometry) from the Oracle server 9, 10 and 11. I use this example beacuse the possibility to select mdsys.sdo_geometry data has been added to odp.net 11.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, that's OK.  Oracle advises that the client version should be >= the server version.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this advice?

Answer (score 4):

See the following document on Metalink.

This contains a matrix of ODP Driver Version, Supported Operating System, SQL*Net, RDBMS, .NET Framework, Visual Studio

Subject:    Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP) Supported Configurations
Doc ID:     726240.1

Comment: This assumes you have a Metalink account.  I am guessing here, but most VS developers trying to access Oracle databases don't have that...

Answer (score 2):

Using an Oracle 11 client against a 10g database will work. I have previously used the 11g client against a 9i database as well.