# oracle 11g thin jdbc driver compatible with oracle 10g database?

Tags: database, oracle10g, driver, oracle11g, jdbc

Currently I'm using the ojdbc14.jar Oracle 10g thin driver to access an Oracle 10g database.

I would like to upgrade the driver to the thin ojdbc6.jar Oracle 11g driver **ahead of** the actual upgrade of the DB server occurs.

Using an 11g driver against the 10g DB seems fine in testing so far, but I'm wondering if anyone can confirm this OK. I looked through the Oracle docs and Readme files but didn't see anything.

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454624/is-it-ok-to-use-oracle-11g-client-with-a-10g-server), but that wasn't for Java and didn't seem to have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the upwards and downwards compatibility is usually pretty good. I've successfully used such configuration several times in the past.

Having said that I remember one occasion, where we had a problem with calling a stored procedure that returned an open cursor to the Java application. Going back to an older version of the OJDBC driver solved it. At the time, it was a Oracle 9i database.

So with some testing, you can become confident it works.