# C#/Oracle: Connect

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, database-connection

i've been trying to find out how to connect a c# program with an oracle 10g db. all code examples i found always used either ado.net oracleclient of .net-framework (which is deprecated -> not good), or system.data.ado, which apparently uses a data source (odbc) -> not allowed to use, or the oracle developer tools odt (like odbc?), which support olny visual studio 2005 for 10g and only 11g for vs 2010... is there any way to connect, like it is possible with delphi (devart, odac), which ive used before i was told to look into the possibilities of connecting c# and oracle?

Comment: see my comment to V4Vendetta below, it should work.  Please post your issues with VS2010, but it does support it. what issues are you having that lead you to believe that the newest versions of ODP do not work with vs2010 and an 10g?  You need to use the 11g client software, but that will connect to 10g (and 9i) ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/faq-093106.html#DBserver )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use [`ODP.NET`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) to perform your actions on oracle database.

This could also be an interesting [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971518) for you

Comment: odp 11 is for oracle 11g, i presume? i have a 10g database, but vs 2010

Comment: There is also one available for 10g, link was for your reference

Comment: you mean to say its not available for Framework 4.0, in any case they are built for backward comaptibility so shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @Eike Cochu ODP it is available for the 4.0 framework (both in 32bit and 64bit).  All ODP's work with Oracle 9i and above.

Comment: if it works without 11g client (even if there a big 11g in the top right corner of the setup and the setup wants my 11g client installation path) then ill gladly install it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use `System.Data.OleDb` which should work fine for any version of Visual Studio and the .Net Framework - unless you need to perform any Oracle-specific queries that are not supported on OleDb.

A big bonus imho is that you won't have to deal with deploying any special 3rd party database driver.

Answer (score 1):

On [connectionstrings.com/oracle](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) you can find several examples of connection string for several providers.

I would recommend something like ODP.NET or OracleClient that uses the native interface to the database.

The data classes are very similar between different databases, so you can just take an example that uses `SqlClient` classes ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0.aspx)) and substitute `OracleClient` classes, and change the connection string.

Comment: OracleClient is deprecated and it seems like odp/odt/odac (all the same?) for 10g is only for vs 2005

Comment: @Eike Cochu: Ok, it seems that MS is dropping their implementation. You can use ODP.NET 11 with a 10g server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454624/is-it-ok-to-use-oracle-11g-client-with-a-10g-server

Answer (score 0):

See the following code ;)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

class OleDbConnectionOracle
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string connectionString = "provider=MSDAORA;data source=ORCL;user id=SCOTT;password=TIGER";
    OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    OleDbCommand myOleDbCommand = myOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();

    myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT empno, ename, sal FROM emp WHERE empno = 7369";

    myOleDbConnection.Open();

    OleDbDataReader myOleDbDataReader = myOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();

    myOleDbDataReader.Read();

    myOleDbDataReader.Close();
    myOleDbConnection.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah thx, is working that way, but this example needs a data source which has to be set up in system preferences, and i just can not setup and maintain these data sources for every single user

Comment: i've never success to connect without this "data source", i don't think that you could get the "oracle data source" of every users ...

Comment: @Eike This OleDb connection doesn't need any system data source configuration.

Comment: it does? the data source is ORCL and it has to be set up beforehand, otherwise how would this program know how to connect to the db

Answer (score 0):

It took very long time to realize my mistake, I was trying to migrate dotnet application from X86 to X64 with oracle data access dependencies.

The oracle connection problem had just gone by moving from OracleConnection to OleDbConnection works well Thanks!.