# Can the oracle client version be superior than Server's?

Tags: oracle, version, compatibility

Is it valid to have that kind of configuration?

E.g:

- Server Version `10g` and Client Version `11g`?
- Server Version `9i` and Client Version `10g`?

Comment: Here speak about this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454624/is-it-ok-to-use-oracle-11g-client-with-a-10g-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Oracle client drivers can talk to older versions of the server. I was using a 10g driver for a long time to access 8 and 9.

The technical term is "Client / Server Interoperability Support", see this page for links: http://blog.oracle48.nl/oracle-database-version-compatibility-and-support-matrix/

Direct links to Oracle (needs Oracle ID): [Client / Server Interoperability Support](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&id=207303.1)

Comment: Perhaps you should know if, is there such a list? Or is just a gues?

Comment: It's not a guess. Google turned up this link: http://blog.oracle48.nl/oracle-database-version-compatibility-and-support-matrix/ You'll need an Oracle ID to access the documents.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know if my question is duplicated, though